# If on an average $9$ ships out of $10$ return safe to the port, what is the chance that out of $5$ ships expected at least $3$ will arrive?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Can you help me solve this question. I have tried to solve it but I don't know how to start...

Comment: Calculate the probability that exactly three will arrive. Add the probability that exactly four will arrive. Add the probability that all five will arrive.

Comment: I don't know how to do this... Can you please explain briefly...

Comment: You have a Bernoulli trial with a probability of success of 9 out of 10 and failure 1 out of 10.

Comment: I have not learned 'Bernoulli trials' yet

Comment: Given that you are a beginner with probability, I assume that the given is that the probability of a ship arriving is $0.9$. So no need for Bernouilli trials. Now, let's start easy: can you calculate the probability of *all* 5 ships arriving?

Comment: yes..............

Comment: OK, how about exactly $4$ ships out of $5$ ships?

Comment: $0.8$ is it okay

Comment: No.  OK, go back to all 5 ships: what is the probability that all 5 ships arrive?

Comment: You have five ships. If a ship arrives safely, we mark it with a $P$ for (arrived in Port). If it does not, we mark it with an $F$ for (Failed to arrive in port). There are $2^5=32$ possible strings using only $P$ or $F$. There are 16 possibilities that have at least 3 P's in them. Write out all of the possibilities. Calculate the probability that the ships arrive or fail to arrive in the sequence you prescribe. Add those probabilities together.

Comment: Okay I understand.....

Comment: Please update your question with the specifics of what you are having trouble with. The questions on this forum should be applicable to others having similar problems, and as stated, your question lacks context and details that would make it useful to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'at least $5$' means: 'exactly $3$ or exactly $4$ or exactly $5$'. Since these are mutually exclusive events, we can write this as:

$$P(\geq 3) = P(3) + P(4) + P(5)$$

Now, $P(5)$ is easy. This would be the probability that the first ship arrives *and* the second ship arrives on time *and* the third ship arrives on time *and* the fourth ship arrives on time *and* the fifth ship arrives on time .  These are supposed to be independent events, and so we can multiply their individual probabilities:

$$P(5) = 0.9 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9 = (0.9)^5$$

Now, let's do $P(4)$.  OK, so you need $4$ ships arriving, and $1$ not.  This can happen in $5$ ways:

First ship does not arrive, but all $4$ others do arrive. The probability of this is $(1-0.9)\cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9 = 0.1 \cdot (0.9)^4$

Second ship does not arrive, but all $4$ others do arrive. The probability of this is $0.9 \cdot (1-0.9)\cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9 = 0.1 \cdot (0.9)^4$

Third ship does not arrive, but all $4$ others do arrive. The probability of this is $0.9 \cdot 0.9 \cdot (1-0.9)\cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9 = 0.1 \cdot (0.9)^4$

Fourth ship does not arrive, but all $4$ others do arrive. The probability of this is $0.9 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9 \cdot (1-0.9)\cdot 0.9 = 0.1 \cdot (0.9)^4$

Fifth ship does not arrive, but all $4$ others do arrive. The probability of this is $0.9 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9\cdot (1-0.9) = 0.1 \cdot (0.9)^4$

These are mutually exclusive, and so we can add these up:

$$P(4) = 0.1 \cdot (0.9)^4 + 0.1 \cdot (0.9)^4 + 0.1 \cdot (0.9)^4 + 0.1 \cdot (0.9)^4 + 0.1 \cdot (0.9)^4 = 5 \cdot 0.1 \cdot (0.9)^4$$

Now, we could have obtained the latter a bit more quickly as follows:

We need $1$ ship not arriving, and $4$ ships arriving. There are $5$ possible 'positions' for that $1$ ship, and so we get $5 \cdot 0.1 \cdot (0.9)^4$

Now, can you figure out how to do $P(3)$, i.e. the probability that exactly $3$ out of $5$ ships arrive?

There is a straight-up formula for this, but first I want you to figure out the underlying mechanics .... *using formulas without understanding where the formula comes from does not teach you anything* ...

Answer (score 2):

In the case where safe returns are independent of each other, if we let $x_i = 1$ when the ship arrives safely, and $0$ otherwise and  probability that a given ship returns safely is $p$, then the chance that exactly $k$ ships return is $${n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}.$$

The general formula for *at least* $k$ out of $n$ ships returning safely is.

$$\sum_{i=k}^n {n \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}$$.

In your specific example $p = 0.9, n = 5, k=3$, this simplifies to
$$p^{3} (6 p^{2} - 15 p + 10)$$ 
or approximately $0.9914$.

Comment: Answer is 12393/12500